# How to place tikz inside table via input

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, multirow

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|ll|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\input{diagrams/classifier.tex} \\
  VAE \\ 
  RNN 
\end{tabular}
&
diagram vrnn 
&
diagram vada 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

creates

[image]

However

```
\input{diagrams/classifier.tex}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|ll|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\input{diagrams/classifier.tex} \\
  VAE \\ 
  RNN 
\end{tabular}
&
diagram vrnn 
&
diagram vada 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

creates

[image]

correctly BUT at the expense of a SECOND diagram somewhere else on the page. How do I get the diagram to show up correctly without adding an extra image? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code for the diagram:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-7.5cm,yshift=-5cm,thick,
node distance=1.6cm,on grid,>=stealth',
comp/.style={circle,draw=black}]
\node [comp]  (input)                       {$x$};
\node [comp]  (latent)  [right=of input]    {$z$} edge [<-,very thick] (input);
\node [comp]  (copy)  [right=of latent]    {$L_y$} edge [<-, very thick](latent);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: also great if you could tell me how to not have the third node touching the border

Comment: adding \usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows} to the main page (this was a sub page) fixed the problem kind of....

Comment: What do you mean by 'kind of'? This was exactly the problem. `\usetikzlibrary` commands should go into the preamble (before `\begin{document}`, but after `\usepackage{tikz}`).

Comment: Regarding your question about space: There is a little bit too much space to the right, originating from the space between `\input{...}` and `\\ `. To get a bit more space above the diagram, insert something like `\\[-1.6ex]` above. The fragment thus reads `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\\[-1.6ex]\input{diagrams/classifier.tex}\\ `.

Comment: Please don't give us fragments. *Especially* when you are asking about 2 diagrams on the same page. Provide code for a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem. Though it seems to have been solved in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all, anyway let me guessing (base on provided images) what is your problem. In this I define the preamble, where I load the following packages:

- `tikz` for drawing diagram
- `makecell` for write multi line cells and add vertical spaces in cells
- `tabularx` for simple set table with prescribed width. Selecting `\texwidth` for table width ensure that table start at left text border and end at right one.
- `graphicx` which enable inclusion of images
- `adjustbox` which is used in positioning of included graphics file in table cell(s)

I consider two cases:

- the code for images is part of table (or it can be imported as .tex file with `\input{<path>/<code name>}`)
- the image exist as .pdf or .png or .jpg  file and is included in table by `\includegraphics[...]{...}` macro:

[image]

MWE, which consider both cases is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
    \hline
% \input{<path>/<code name>}
% or put image code directly here
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
node distance = 1.6cm, on grid,
  start chain = going right,  
  comp/.style = {circle,draw=black,on chain},
every path/.style = {thick, -Stealth}
                    ]
\node [comp]  (input)   {$x$};
\node [comp]  (latent)  {$z$};
\node [comp]  (copy)    {$L_y$} edge [<-, very thick](latent);
\draw   (input)  edge (latent) 
        (latent)  to  (copy);
\end{tikzpicture}
                        & diagram vrnn  &   diagram vada    \\
\makecell[l]{VAE\\ RNN} &               &                   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
    \hline
\includegraphics[width=38mm, height=11mm,
                 margin=0pt 2pt, valign=t]{example-image}
                        & diagram vrnn  &   diagram vada    \\
\makecell[l]{VAE\\ RNN} &               &                   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Let me know, if my guessing are correct. If not, please clarify your question. The best way is provide complete small document (it can be based on the my answer), which show your problem.